# Are Swift Property Wrappers attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

Using a `propertyWrapper`seems to have the same syntax as `attribute`. For instance, compare this custom `propertyWrapper`:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Capitalize {
    private var value: String = ""
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get { return value.capitalized }
        set {
            value = newValue }
        
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.value = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

and when using it:

```
@Capitalize
var myProperty: String = "hello world"
```

Compare this to `attributes`such as `@IBOutlet` or `@available` or even `@propertyWrapper` which are basically compiler information: they look the same. So my question is: Are `propertyWrappers` `attributes` or are they considered separare?

As mention above, `propertyWrappers` make use of an `attribute`: `@propertyWrapper`. But is the wrapper itself an `attribute`?

My own take on this is that this part:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Capitalize {
    private var value: String = ""
...
```

is called `propertWrapper`, which creates your very own `attribute` to use on any `property`.

So, that would make this the `attribute`:

`@Capitalize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, property wrappers are attributes. If we consult [the Swift grammar](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/summaryofthegrammar), we find this production:

> *attribute* → `@` *attribute-name* *attribute-argument-clause?*

And that is the only `@` in the grammar. So anything that starts with an `@` (and is otherwise valid syntax) is, according to Swift's definitions, an “attribute”.

You can read more in [the “Attributes” section of *The Swift Programming Language*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Attributes provide metadata about a program construct and give the compiler additional information or directives for compilation. Some commonly used attributes are **`@available`**, **`@discardableResult`**, **`@IBAction`**, and **`@IBOutlet`**.

They don't contain business logic like property wrappers. Instead, they annotate code elements to affect their behavior or provide hints to the compiler.

For example, **`@IBOutlet`** is an attribute that tells the compiler that a property is an "Interface Builder outlet", enabling you to connect it to Interface Builder.

So while property wrappers are declared using an attribute `(@propertyWrapper)`, they themselves are not considered attributes. They are a way to create custom behaviors around property access, whereas attributes are more like annotations for the compiler.

So mainly

Property Wrappers are more like templates for how to manage the getting and setting of a property value. They encapsulate behavior and can be reused.

On the other hand

Attributes provide additional metadata or directives to the compiler but don't encapsulate behavior in the same way property wrappers do.

Comment: I don't agree. There are [attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/attributes/#dynamicCallable) that definitely have to have business logic, also resultBuilder. Some attributes may serve as essentially compiler directives, but I'd argue you'd need proof to confidently say they _don't_ have business logic. propertyWrapper is just an attribute that produces other custom named attributes, that are then also able to be called property wrappers. Just my opinion.